# Distinguish languages when displaying stack snippets

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code, stack-snippets

I just integrated my first snippet on an existing post, nice work.

I put it on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19932511/731138

[image]

Code appears without language distinction, with a small space as separation:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    alert("Checkbox state (right method 1) = " + $('#test').is(':checked'));
    alert("Checkbox state (right method 2) = " + $('#test').prop('checked'));
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check me: <input id="test" type="checkbox" />
```

I think it would be more readable if the language for each code were explicitly given:

<kbd>JavaScript</kbd>

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    alert("Checkbox state (right method 1) = " + $('#test').is(':checked'));
    alert("Checkbox state (right method 2) = " + $('#test').prop('checked'));
});
```

<kbd>HTML</kbd>

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check me: <input id="test" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 4):

`<html/>`
`c:ss`
`javascript.().()`
and
`j$q$u$e$r$y`
are all very distinct formatted languages that I think they are quite easy to tell apart without writing
**LANGUAGE**
on top of each one separately.