# Network Profile showing wrong answer count

Tags: bug, network-profile, answer-count

I was just looking at my [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5924590/tot-zam?tab=accounts) accounts page, and noticed that it says I have zero answers on Meta Stack Exchange:

> [image: network profile]

If you look at the [answer tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/297762/tot-zam?tab=answers) in my profile activity, however, you will see that I do have 1 answer:

> [image: answer tab]

I posted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260246/297762) almost 2 years ago, so this does not look like a delay or sync issue.

My Meta Stack Exchange account has always been part of my main account, so this is not a case of the number being off because of merged accounts, like I had [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269081/merging-accounts-didnt-merge-number-of-questions-on-network-profile).

Why is the Network Profile count not showing the correct answer count?

Comment: @iBug A 2 year delay? Like I mentioned in my question, I posted that answer 2 years ago. Also, I posted 3 new questions today and the question number immediately updated from 4 to 7. The answer amount, however, remained at 0.

Comment: LOL... Maybe the cache failed to update when you post that answer, and it remained "intact" ever since.

Comment: Happens to me [as well](https://stackexchange.com/users/5992041/neinstein?tab=accounts). Apparently I got 679 rep on Travel SE for doing absolutely nothing. (False: a year ago I wrote one half-answer that accidently became viral. So not *that* far from thruth actually...)