# Wrong # of answers on network profile

Tags: bug, answers, network-profile

My [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts) claims that I have only one answer on [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/):

[image]

but I actually have [two](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22845/glorfindel?tab=answers), both from September this year so it's hard to blame caching.

[image]

There are more people reporting this, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298908/295232), but I do have a hunch *why* this happens in my case; [this answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/199273/22845) had been converted to a comment to the question, and was later undeleted by a ♦ moderator. See the [timeline](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/199273/timeline). Could it be that this event somehow doesn't propagate correctly to the network profile?