# Wrong number of questions/answers in network profile (yes, again)

Tags: bug, network-profile

This is an issue that has been reported a couple of times, but *maybe* with a different cause than now - see below.

I noticed the number of questions/answers displayed on some of my accounts on [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/13177264/jenayah?tab=accounts) is wrong, as well as at least another user's. I've been keeping my eyes on it for a couple of days to see if it disappeared on its own, but it didn't.

My History of Science and Mathematics account shows me having asked 0 questions, while I did - I thought my one question on HSM might have been deleted, but no, [it's still up](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7762/7929). Same goes for Meta, supposedly 3 questions, when it's really [four](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/398063/jenayah?tab=questions) (or five, with this one).

> [image: wrong number of Meta Qs on my own account]
>   [image: wrong number of HSM Qs on my own account]

It got me curious and I browsed around a couple of random user profiles throughout the network; out of ~20 (which, granted, might not reflect the hundreds of thousands accounts there are out there), the only one I found with a discrepancy is [the user who answered my HSM question](https://stackexchange.com/users/3776439/valorum?tab=accounts); his network profile states he provided 10 answers on HSM, while as far as I can see, there's [only one](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7763/7929).

> [image: wrong number of HSM As on Richard's account]

Browsing around Meta a bit brought up the fllowing questions, the causes of which don't seem applicable here:

1. [Wrong # of answers on network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319316/398063): the most recent one that I could find; but this might be due to the answer having a very unusual timeline (deleted, converted into a comment, undeleted), while none of this applies in both examples given above;
2. [Network Profile showing wrong answer count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298908/398063) was "solved" of sorts by posting new content on the buggy site. Actually, this one is probably the closest; if posting the present question updates my counter, this could mean they're dupes<sup>1</sup>. However, I posted an answer on Meta since the last time I asked a question, and the counter still displays 3. *(Posting a dummy question on HSM and ninja-delete it for the sake of testing a bug felt inappropriate)*. Probably the same as [Network Profile showing wrong answer count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298908/398063) as well.
3. [Account page incorrectly showing 0 answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136417/398063) appears to be part of a dupe-chain of temporary-bug-stuff from 7 years ago.

The most blatant difference with the above earlier questions is that in this case, part of the "bug" is that at least one user saw their amount of answer **tenfolded** (instead of being less than expected).

- Is this only some kind of "caching" bug that requires whomever with the right tool to sync it manually?
- Any ideas on how to reproduce rather than justing browsing random profiles?
- Are these two bugs (showing less/showing more than expected) caused by the same thing? I can imagine the script *missing* on some questions, but *adding* others where there aren't any?

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, it's now been 6 to 8 days, and the bug persists; despite me having posted a new question (two, even), the profile still shows 5. (instead of 6)